# NSDictionary returning nil when unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create detection options for a CIDetector. The NSDictionary i'm creating to hold the detection options keeps giving me the error "unexpected found nil while unwrapping optional value". I've gotten this error but I can't seem to figure it out this time around.

```
var detectorOptions:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: CIDetectorAccuracyLow,CIDetectorAccuracy)
```

Comment: That error means the dictionary is nil.

Comment: I understand the error, I don't understand why i'm getting it because I should be creating the dictionary with that bit of code.

Comment: This line gives you the error?

Comment: yes, I put breakpoints in and the program fails after that line of code

Comment: Does the program crash on that line or on a different line?

Comment: It crashes on that line

Comment: It crashes after that line of code runs....so on that line. Sorry if that was confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74138/discussion-between-nobodynada-and-user3353890).

Comment: I tested it in the playground and it works just fine passing nil to CIDetector.  Does it work for you, or does it crash again?

Comment: I restarted xcode, cleaned my build, and now I can pass nil to CIDetector as well....not sure why it wasn't working before. Thanks again for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NobodyNada for the assistance. The correct answer is:

```
var detectorOptions:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: CIDetectorAccuracyLow, forKey: CIDetectorAccuracy)
```